# Zend Framework 1.11 + Doctrine 2 + Class Inheritance mapping (YAML) problems with generate entities

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm, class-table-inheritance

I get number of problems trying to implement CTI

First of all I use a custom loader for my entity classes

```
class My_AutoLoader implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface
{

    public function autoload($class)
    {
        $class = trim(str_replace('\\', '/', $class), '/');
        if (@include(APPLICATION_PATH . '/Entities/' . $class . '.php')) {
            return $class;
        } else {
            throw new Zend_Loader_Exception('Cannot load ' . $class . '.');
        }
    }

}
```

The idea is to use `application\Entities` for classes that have no namespace
like `$user = new Users();`

Then I have defined class inheritance

```
Profiles:
  type: entity
  table: profiles
  repositoryClass: Repositories\Base
  inheritanceType: JOINED
  discriminatorColumn:
    name: profiletype
    type: integer
    length: 11
  discriminatorMap:
    1: Personal
    2: Work
    3: Business
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    firstname:
      type: string
      length: 255
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    ...


Work:
  type: entity
  table: work
  repositoryClass: Repositories\Base
  fields:
    position:
      type: string
      length: 255
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
```

then I have manually created the class Work to extend Profiles

```
class Work extends Profiles
{
}
```

The first problem begun with 2.0.0 (2.0.1), when I use console tool's *generate-entities* I get the error that **I don't have id's for the `Work` class**, it is odd because IMHO it contradicts with the idea that `Work` extends `Profiles` and `id` is already defined.

However I tried to add a column `id` for the `Work` class, but then **I get a message that I already have a column `id`**. DOH!

I tried to add some other column name for PK but I actually get an **extra column that is unnecessary** because the proper inherited column `id` is also created. In CTI i should have a single FK column and there are no other PK's with auto-generated values.

So I did the *bad thing* to hack the doctrine classes and remove the checks for missing id's. Ugly but it worked. The entities start to generate properly and the db structure is just fine.

I later found that all that strange behavior is due to a bug in doctrine 2 and *it is fixed* in 2.0.5.

Well, I tried 2.0.5 and **had exactly the same problem**, so I thought the mistake is in my code.

I filed a bug in doctrine's jira and **I got answered that my definitions are wrong** and I need id's for subclasses (and got referred to the documentation that all we know is quite poor, especially for YAML mapping). I gave up and sticked with my hack.

Later I tried with 2.0.6 and 2.1 but with those versions my entities are no longer updated but **each time i use generate-entities the new class definitions are being append to the end so there are duplicates**.

My question is:

Is this a problem with doctrine or I am doing it wrong?

If it is in me what is the proper way of mapping CI

Comment: I have successfully used CTI from 2.0.4 to 2.1 with annotations. Entity subclasses don't need ID field, you can be sure of that. A FK/PK id field is nonetheless automatically created by Doctrine in the subclasses DB tables. Try creating your schemas programatically following these instructions: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation . I can post my own code if you think it helps (but its with annotations, not yaml).

Comment: actually I often used the annotations for reference to make the more complex definitions, but seems I'm doing it the proper way, probably the bug is in generate-entities and probably confused by my autoloader which the only odd thing I'm using (that is why I also provided it). Btw the db schema is created just fine if I fix my entities (remove the duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from your question:

> *Update:*
>   I found that the problem is actually a bug in Doctrine which always prefix the namespace with "\" when updating entities and my custom autoloader loads only classes without namespace. In addition there is a bug with inheriting properties (ids)
>
> *Both will be fixed in 2.1.1*